# Python List mutable

Tags: python, list, android-listview, mutable, primitive-types

I am trying to use Python term to explain why the following happens, can somebody explain why `tmp` becomes to `[[1,2,3]]` not stay as `[[1,2]]`?

```
arr = []
tmp = [1,2]
arr.append(tmp)
print arr # [[1,2]]
tmp.append(3)
print arr # [[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: `arr.append(tmp)` does not copy the list referred to by `tmp`.  It just adds another reference to the same list at the end of  `arr`.  So now `arr[0]` and `tmp` refer to the same object.

Comment: [immutable vs mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: This is just the basic semantics of simple Python assignment. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr = []` is an empty list, and when you append `tmp` to it via:

```
tmp = [1, 2]
arr.append(tmp)
```

You are putting `tmp` in the `arr` list, thus giving you `arr = [tmp]` which can be expanded to `arr = [[1,2]]`. But the neat thing here is that you maintain a reference to to the list, `[1,2]` via the `temp` variable. Thus, when you append `temp` you are appending the same list that is in `arr`.

For a bit further clarification, just because you are appending `tmp` to `arr` doesn't mean that the resulting list `[[1,2]]` is all going to be one continuous block in memory. You are going to have the `arr` list and the first element of `arr` is going to be a pointer to the list `tmp`.

Comment: So append in python list is like copy by reference in C++ rather than copy by value?

Comment: `append` appends the passed object onto the list and in your example above no copying is being done. The original `tmp` object is the one that is being added to the list, so when you change `tmp` you change the list that is now in `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

All the comments are great ones.

```
arr.append(tmp)
print arr # [[1,2]]
```

As you can see, the result is NOT:

```
print arr # [1,2]
```

So, `arr` just holds the reference to `tmp` array. If my guess is write you are looking for:

```
 arr.extend(tmp)
 print arr # [1,2]
```

More on [difference between `append` vs. `extend` list methods in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of both `tmp` and `arr[0]` points to the same object.
Just check it here, step by step:

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

[First print statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/steRk.png)
[Second print statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go7Sj.png)

You can manually check it by using `id` built-in

```
>>> arr = []
>>> tmp = [1,2]
>>> arr.append(tmp)
>>> id(tmp)
4404123192
>>> id(arr[0])
4404123192
>>> assert id(tmp) == id(arr[0])
>>> tmp.append(3) # allocate more memory (if needs) and add '3' to object (list) with id 4404123192
>>> id(tmp)
4404123192
>>> id(arr[0])
4404123192
>>> print arr
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: " # allocate more memory " that is misleading, no new memory is allocated necessarily. Generally this is not a helpful way about thinking of things in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga reason to write this comment was to show, that even on memory reallocation, both variables are kept pointing to the same object. There are some cases with other `append` semantics, for example like golang works with slices.