# Getting different output for append or list in python

Tags: python, list, append

```
o=[]
o1=[1,2,3]
o.append(o1)
o1.append(9)
o.append(o1)
print(o)
```

for the above code I've been getting the output  [[1, 2, 3, 9], [1, 2, 3, 9]] but i want to get the output as  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 9]]. So what do i do ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53055087/1431750) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
o=[]
o1=[1,2,3]
o.append(o1)
o1.append(9)
o.append(o1)
print(o)
```

creates `o` holding your `o1` `list` twice (if you want to check it yourself, print `id(o[0])` and `id(o[1])` and compare them), you need to append copies i.e. do:

```
import copy
o=[]
o1=[1,2,3]
o.append(copy.deepcopy(o1))
o1.append(9)
o.append(copy.deepcopy(o1))
print(o)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 9]]
```